# GTM trigger on image showing

Tags: analytics

Struggling with the DOM visible/element variables. Below is the code on page:

Below is the code, if either that image shows (failed.png) or the text says "Sorry! Something isn't quite right." I want to fire a trigger. How would I go about this? I'll also have a different trigger if it's successful, which would be a different image.

```
<div class="page page--result result center">
    <img src="/images/fb/failed.png" class="result__img result__img--success"/>
        <p>Sorry! Something isn't quite right.</p>
        <br/>
```

Thanks

david

Comment: Anyone able to help...?

Comment: It seems like an old question. Is the display of the error message handled at the server side (i.e., html rendering) or javascript logic, etc.?